# Rails assert_select not finding HAML elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assertions

Trying to assert that my error panel is being displayed when trying to create an invalid object.

I have this test ::

```
test 'invalid category submission results in failure' do
  get new_category_path
  assert_template 'categories/new'
  assert_no_difference 'Category.count' do
    post_via_redirect categories_path, category: {name: ''}
  end
  assert_template 'categories/new'
  assert_select 'h2.panel-title'    #<---Problem here
  assert_select 'div.panel-body'
  # assert_match 'prohibited', response.body  #<---This works
end
```

---

The UI displays this ::
[image]

---

I get this error when executing the test ::

```
1) Failure:
CreateCategoriesTest#test_invalid_category_submission_results_in_failure [/Users/jeffrey/Documents/workspace/Ruby/Udemy_Rails_Course/rails_projects/alpha-blog/test/integration/create_categories_test.rb:23]:
Expected at least 1 element matching "h2.panel-title", found 0..
Expected 0 to be >= 1.
```

---

If I comment out the 2 "assert_select" statements and uncomment the "assert_match" statement, then my test passes because it detects the word "prohibited" in the response.body.

So any ideas on why the "assert_select" isn't finding my elements, even though they're clearly there?

Comment: Are you sure that you're looking at the right template?

Comment: Yeah, it's rendering the correct template and the template contains those elements. When I do an assertion on the text being rendered, then it passes. It just doesn't seem to detect any HAML elements.